# Which District is Which?

Tags: crackdown-2

There are various statistics in *Crackdown 2* that tell you how many of a certain thing you've found in each area of the game.  Problem is, I can't remember which area is which, and there's no indication in the game other than the first time you enter a new zone.  This means the statistics are effectively useless to me at the moment.  The districts are labeled as:

- Hope Springs
- Green Bay
- Unity Heights
- Agency Island

Included is a map of the FIRST Crackdown's pacific city, because the only maps I could find of the second one contain orb spoilers.

[image: Map of Pacific City]

Based on this map of the first game, can someone fill me in on which of these areas is which in *Crackdown 2* (i.e. which colour shown here is which area)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The northern yellow area is **Green Bay North**
- The southern yellow island is **Green Bay South**
- The northern blue area above the highway is **Unity Heights North**
- The 2 islands below the highway are **Unity Heights South**
- The northern red area is **Hope Springs North**
- The southern red area is **Hope Springs South**
- **Agency Island** is the purple area in the middle

You can find a whole overview of the areas on [this map](http://achievementhunter.com/games/guides/crackdown2/). It is a zoomed out view, and you need to click on the separate districts to zoom in to see the orb locations, but you don't see them in the overview. So if you're worried about orb spoilers, you can safely look at this map without getting spoiled.